# How to preload data inside indexeddb for Cordova apps?

Tags: javascript, cordova, indexeddb, preload

I'm at abstraction phase by the way. I would like to understand, how can one pre-load some big (allowed) data inside `indexeddb` for offline usage inside **Cordova**.

Suppose, I've fixed documentation drafts and am creating a Cordova application for those documents for offline usage. Those documents amount around 10mb of data. How can I preload this 10mb of data inside `indexeddb` and build my app.

Comment: Also suggest some accessible title for this question

Answer (score 0):

You can insert data into indexeddb, after the database has been created inside the 'onupgradeneeded' event. This event is fired only when the database schema is created or any version change is detected.

If you want to make it more easy - use [jsstore](http://jsstore.net/) or you can use any other idb library. jsstore provides createdDb, openDb and others api to suit your need.

e.g - check out the example link - http://jsstore.net/example/where : it inserts some data into indexeddb when you visit the site for first time.

you can also check the example for more -
 https://ujjwalguptaofficial.github.io/ShopStore/